# How to identify if file is still written or completed through linux script

Tags: linux, shell, sh, lsof

We have one system which is generating files and I want to check which files out of many files are completed and also not been modified from past two minutes through a script and finally rename those.

This is what I tried but the result is not correct. Could someone help?

```
for file in /home/test/*abc_YYYYMMDDhhmmss*
do
    f1=`basename $file`
    if [ lsof | grep "$f1" = "" ];then
        if  [ `stat --format=%Y $file` -le $(( `date +%s` - 300 )) ]; then
        mv "$f1" "${f1}_Complete"
    else
       echo "no files to collect"
    fi
done
```

Comment: What is `if [ lsof | grep "$f1" = "" ]`?  Even if `[` worked like this, the casual reader would expect that the author's intent was to check that the output of grep was non-empty, but `grep "$f1" = ""` looks like a call to `grep` with `=` as a filename.  You can always just check the value returned by grep.  eg `if ! lsof | grep -q "$f1"; then` does what I *think* you're trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making the common mistake of assuming that `[` is part of the `if` command's syntax; but it's not: `[` is just another command. The syntax for an `if` statement is

```sh
if commands; then
    : what to do if the exit code from commands was 0
else
    : what to do if not
fi
```

where `commands` can be an arbitrarily complex sequence of commands, and the exit code from the last command in the sequence decides which branch to take; and the `else` branch is optional.

As a minimal fix, change to

```sh
    # use modern $(command substitution) syntax
    # instead of obsolescent `command substitution`;
    # always quote variables with file names
    f1=$(basename "$file")
    # Remove [ and switch to grep -q;
    # add -F to grep flags for literal matching
    if ! lsof | grep -Fq "$f1"; then
```

Anyway, what about something like this instead?

```sh
find $(lsof |
    awk 'NR==FNR { if ($9 ~ /^\/home\/test\//) a[$9]++; next }
    FNR == 1 {
        if (! (FILENAME in a)) print FILENAME;
        next }' - /home/test/*abc_YYYYMMDDhhmmss*) \
    -type f -mmin +2 -exec sh -c '
        for file; do
            mv "$file" "${file}_Complete"
        done' _ {} +
```

This is pretty complex, but here's a rundown.

- `lsof | awk ...` prints out the files which are not open from the wildcard matches.

  - This assumes that the files are regular text files - some Awk variants have trouble with binary input files. It would probably not be too hard to refactor this to avoid this constraint if it's proplematic.
  - In some more detail, the first argument to Awk is `-` i.e. standard input, which reads the pipe from `lsof`. The condition `NR==FNR` is true for the first input file; we simply collect the open files into the associative array `a`. Then the second condition prints the name of the current input file if it's not in the array; this is executed for the remaining input files, i.e. those which match the wildcard.
- This is passed as the paths for `find` to examine; it will look for any files modified in the last two minutes, and pass the result to the command in `-exec`.
- The simple shell script in `-exec` should be easy to understand. `find` passes the found files as command-line arguments, but `sh -c` fills them from `$0` so we pass in a dummy `_` to push the file names into `$1`, `$2` etc which is what `for` loops over if you don't give it a list of arguments.

This will probably not work if your file names contain newlines; then you'll need something more complex still.

Looping over arbitrary file names is disappointingly complex in Bourne-family shells, and finding elements *not* in a list is always slightly pesky in shell script. Ksh and Bash offer some relief because they have arrays, but this is not portable to POSIX `sh` / `ash` / `dash`.

Comment: hi thanks for the update i tried to incorporate the changes you mentioned and this what i could do with the code the issue is it takes lot of time to run.                                                 
 `for file in /home/test/*abc_YYYYMMDDhhmmss*
do`
    `f1=`basename $file`
 `if  lsof | grep "$f1" = "" ; then
  if  `stat --format=%Y $file` -le $(( `date +%s` - 300 )) ; then

   mv "$f1" "${f1}_Complete"

        else
           echo "no files to collect"
        fi 
done `

Comment: If I can guess where there is supposed to be punctuation in that, it looks like you reverted half of the important and useful changes.

Answer (score 0):

How about this way?

```
#!/bin/bash
find /home/test/* -type f -mmin +2 -print0 |
    while IFS= read -r -d '' line; do
            echo $line
            fuser -s "$line"
            mv "$line" "${line}_Completed"
    done
```

`-mmin +2` means the files that have not been modified in the last 2 minutes.

Edit: as requested, I have changed it to [check if the file is currently open](https://serverfault.com/questions/359945/how-to-list-files-that-are-not-open-using-find-command). `fuser -s "$line"` line will exit if the file is currently opened, else it will proceed to move the file. I have also wrapped the variables in quotes, thanks for the heads up

Comment: Hi Jay thanks for the update but this method is only checking for one condition if file is not modified from last two mins i want to add one more condition to check if the file is currently being modified or open by some other user. Could you help to configure that

Comment: [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: @RohitShamdasani I have updated the code, please check